# Can a ring of spell storing store a spell as a ritual and then cast it in the normal cast time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, rituals

Let's use *silence*, for example. As a ritual, it takes 10 minutes and 6 seconds to cast, using no spell slot. My understanding is that it can be stored in the *ring of spell storing* being cast as a ritual.

When consuming the stored spell, does the cast have to use the same cast time as was used to put the spell in the ring or do they have to use the non-ritual cast time, or can they choose?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Storing a spell in the ring requires the use of a slot

From the description of the [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing), this is not immediately obvious but it does state that:

> The level of the slot used to cast the spell determines how much space it uses.

Fortunately, Jeremy Crawford has clarified this in [a series of tweets](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/901875657432371200):

> **Armando Doval**‏ @armando_doval
>
> @JeremyECrawford can you cast a spell into a Ring of Spell Storing without expending a slot? Description seems to assume slot is used.
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>
> Casting a spell into a ring of spell storing does require a spell slot. #DnD
>
> **AdventuresInLethargy** @theactualevan
>
> I guess ritual casting into a spell storing item is out too, then?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>
> Correct
>
> **Uri-AHH!**‏ @Panoramic_Panda
>
> Can you cast a spell into a Ring of Spell Storing from a wand?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>
> It requires a spell slot. A wand doesn't expend a spell slot.

So this means that any method that does not use a spell slot can't be used to store spells in a ring of spell storing.

Comment: Nice find! It's the slot level that matters, not the spell level. Which makes sense for upcasting, too.