# Can a Shadow Sorcerer see through Darkness cast into a Ring of Spell Storing via Eyes of the Dark?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, sorcerer

A sorcerer with the Shadow Magic origin has a feature called Eyes of the Dark, which states the following (XGTE, p. 51):

> When you reach 3rd level in this class, you learn the *darkness* spell, which doesn't count against your number of sorcerer spells known. In addition, you can cast it by spending 2 sorcery points or by expending a spell slot. **If you cast it with sorcery points, you can see through the darkness created by the spell.**

A [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) (DMG, p. 192) states:

> This ring stores spells cast into it, holding them until the attuned wearer uses them.
>   ...
>   Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast. The spell has no effect, other than to be stored in the ring.
>   ...
>   While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell.

If a sorcerer cast *darkness* using sorcery points as per their Eyes of the Dark feature into the Ring of Spell Storing, then when they later "released" the spell from the ring, would they be able to see through the darkness as per their Eyes of the Dark feature?

(Bonus question: what if the ring was used by someone else; would the sorcerer who cast the spell originally still see though it, even though someone else "released" the spell? This is just out of interest, though; the main question I care about is in the case where the sorcerer uses the ring.)

I imagine one could argue yes, because it was originally cast via sorcery points, but one could also argue no, because of the technicality of the ring's description saying "but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell", or something like that. Which is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### You can't store the spell in the Ring without using a slot

Unfortunately, casting darkness with sorcery points makes it not storable in the ring of spell storing. (Copy pasted from [my answer here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133815/33707)), based both on the description of the ring:

> The level of the slot used to cast the spell determines how much space it uses.

And the tweets by Jeremy Crawford:

> **Armando Doval**‏ @armando_doval
>
> @JeremyECrawford can you cast a spell into a Ring of Spell Storing without expending a slot? Description seems to assume slot is used.
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>
> Casting a spell into a ring of spell storing does require a spell slot. #DnD
>
> **AdventuresInLethargy** @theactualevan
>
> I guess ritual casting into a spell storing item is out too, then?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>
> Correct
>
> **Uri-AHH!**‏ @Panoramic_Panda
>
> Can you cast a spell into a Ring of Spell Storing from a wand?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>
> It requires a spell slot. A wand doesn't expend a spell slot.

Naturally, Jeremy Crawford's rulings have since [lost some weight](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140222/33707) so your take on this requirement may be different.

### What if you could store it?

If we ignore the spell slot requirement (or simply choose to interpret differently), the Ring of Spell Storing still specifies exactly what is maintained from the first casting:

> The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell.

This means that other than these specific factors, nothing else is taken into account from the original caster and the sorcerer would therefore not be able to see through the darkness, regardless of who is wearing the ring.

This is a similar reasoning than what can be found [in this related Q/A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76572/33707)